Simple question on difference between polar and cartesian representation of complex number
I want to compute $y=Re[a_n e^{2\pi n x i}]$, where $a_n$ is complex. The first way I compute it is let $a_n=re^{i\theta}$ then $y=Re[re^{i(\theta+2\pi n x)}]=r\cos{(\theta+2\pi n x)}.$ The second way I compute it is let $e^{2\pi n x i}=\cos{2\pi n x}+i\sin{2\pi n x}$ and $a_n = a+bi$. Then $y=Re[(a+bi)(\cos{2\pi n x}+i\sin{2\pi n x})] = a\cos{2\pi n x} - b\sin{2\pi n x}$.
So in the first case I get a cos term and in the second both a sin and cos! My understanding is that you can write any complex number $x+yi$ as $re^{i\theta}$ so why is there this difference?

You forgot an $r$ in the first evaluation

@Zima You are right, I've added it in, thanks. But this doesn't change the premise of the question no?

Notice that $a=r\cos\theta$, and $b=r\sin\theta$, so
$$a\cos{2\pi n x} - b\sin{2\pi n x}=r(\cos\theta\cos{2\pi n x}-\sin\theta\sin{2\pi n x})$$
Does this ring a bell? What about cosine angle sum formula?
